# Login using iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to make a login page with xcode.

I have read all the topics about this, and I'm pretty sure that my app sends username and
password to the webpage succesfully.

But my problem is that when I'm calling a response string I still get the sourcecode
from the login screen on the webpage. 
When my app sends the password and username, where do I go from here?

Im using ASIformdatarequest to POST username and password.

Here my code where I send the username and password

(Brugernavn = username, and Adgangskode = Password)

```
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://coutbound.dk/login.asp"]];

    [request setPostValue:[self.bnavn text] forKey:@"Brugernavn"];
    [request setPostValue:[self.kord text] forKey:@"Adgangskode"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];


}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Request failed: %@",[request error]);
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Submitted form successfully");
    NSLog(@"Response was:");
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
}
```

And the webpage

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login script</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet title=std href="typografi.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: transparent;">
    <img border="0" src="aeble.gif" width="161" height="120">

    <form method="POST" action="login.asp">
    <table border="0" width="100%" height="2">
      <tr>
        <td width="41%" height="1">
          <p align="left"><script language="JavaScript">
            day = new Date()
            hr = day.getHours()
            if (hr < 5)
            hilsen = "God aften"
            if (hr >= 5)
            hilsen = "God morgen"
            if (hr >= 10)
            hilsen = "God formiddag"
            if (hr >= 12)
            hilsen = "God eftermiddag"
            if (hr >= 17)
            hilsen = "God aften"
            document.write(hilsen)
            </script>  og velkommen<script>
            today = new Date();
            document.write(' på COutbound i dag den '+today.getDate()+'. ')
            tmonth = today.getMonth()
            if (tmonth==0) document.write('januar ')
            if (tmonth==1) document.write('februar ')
            if (tmonth==2) document.write('marts ')
            if (tmonth==3) document.write('april ')
            if (tmonth==4) document.write('maj ')
            if (tmonth==5) document.write('juni ')
            if (tmonth==6) document.write('juli ')
            if (tmonth==7) document.write('august ')
            if (tmonth==8) document.write('september ')
            if (tmonth==9) document.write('oktober ')
            if (tmonth==10) document.write('november ')
            if (tmonth==11) document.write('december ')
            document.write(today.getUTCFullYear())
            document.write('<br>')
            s = 'December 24, '
            if (today.getMonth()==11)
            if (today.getDate()>24) {
            if (today.getYear()<100)
            s += today.getYear() + 1901
            else s += today.getYear() +1
            }
            else s += today.getYear()
            if (today.getMonth()==11)
            if (today.getDate()==24)
            document.write('<font size=+2>så idag er det Juleaften</font>')
            else {
            BigDay = new Date(s)
            msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
            timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
            e_daysLeft = (timeLeft / msPerDay)+1;
            daysLeft = Math.floor (e_daysLeft);
            document.write('der er '+daysLeft+' dage til Juleaften i ');
            if (BigDay.getYear()<100)
            document.write(BigDay.getYear()+1900)
            else document.write(BigDay.getYear())
            document.write('</font><p>')
            }
            </script></p>
            <p style="margin: 0">Angiv brugernavn og adgangskode herunder. Har du ikke brugernavn og adgangskode skal du oprette dig som bruger
              ved at klikke på linket under formularen!
          </tr>
        </table>

  <table border="0" width="45%" height="47">
    <tr>
      <td width="50%" height="26">Brugernavn:</td>
      <td width="50%" height="26"><input type="text" name="Brugernavn" size="25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="26">Adgangskode:</td>
      <td height="26"><input type="password" name="Adgangskode" size="25"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="Action" style="font-size: 8pt"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" align="center" colspan="2" height="25" valign="bottom"><a href="Login2.asp">Opret ny bruger</a>&nbsp&nbsp<a href="forgotp.asp">Jeg har glemt mit kodeord</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution**

I solved my problem making a post to the button "action" with value "login"

Comment: Post some code. Your description is too generic to let us help you.

Comment: NSURLConnection will allow you do a simple POST to a website or webservice. But post some code so we can see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a simple PHP interface API for your application like something below?

```
<?php
 $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
 $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

 $exists = mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($exists > 0) {
     $array = array('success' => 1);
 } else {
     $array = array('success' => 0);
 }

 echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Then let your app listen for the response JSON and check if success is 1 or 0.  If it's 1, then you've logged in successfully.  Otherwise there was an error finding it in the database.

Comment: We have tested that it POST correctly on our own homepage, but we do not have any control with the webpage we are trying to log in to. If we asume that my code is correct, do we need any session ID or something like that to look at the rest of the page?

Comment: Is this not your own webpage?  Are you trying to login to a third party website and get the results from that?

Comment: Im building an app for my workplace and its their webpage that we want to login to. (They have given me permision to do so). But everytime we try to get information we get redirected to the frontpage